# Window doesn't render as expected, controls gets messed up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSWindow` with autolayout, There is one view based `NSTableView` with few controls like images and labels . Once in a while the window comes ugly, means all the constraints doesn't work, and the text fields, images just loose their places.

All the controls inside the tableView are seen in (0,0). But only for few rows, for other rows it work perfectly, however all rows contains same controls.

This is happening only for the first time specially in OSX 10.10 when installing from DMG, if I reopen the window again then every thing look OK, no overlapping of text and other controls.

Please help to understand the issue, or any suggestion to fix.

Comment: Please post code or IB screenshots. No way to know otherwise.

Comment: Unless your problem can be attributed to some well-known issue in Auto Layout's 10.10 implementation, I don't think there's enough detail in your question to allow others to provide targeted help. Can you explain the Auto Layout setup in a bit more detail, or better still provide a sample project which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @uchuugaka: I can not show you the screen shot, due to some policies. And the autolayout is done using IB only, not a single line of code used for it.

Comment: @PaulPatterson: I have updated my question, lets check if that helps to understand.

Comment: It doesn't help much I'm afraid. Although you create the constraints in Interface Builder you could still log them to the console, and add the log to your question. If you decide to do this, it'd alos be a good idea to format the output so people don't have to wade through reams of irrelevant information - the ``description`` property of ``NSLayoutConstraint`` is pretty verbose.